# AJAX load method error 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am french, I am working on website optimisation with AJAX but I have a strange error. I explain with code

I am working with php file. In this php file we built a table with id='ajax'

```
<table id='ajax' width='100%'> <!-- On cré un nouveau tableau qui prend toute la largeur de la page -->
```

This table is feed with php data (echo + html code)

Just aside we have an other php file named ajax_v2.php which normaly feed the table after javascript and AJAX request.

So, I want to use load method from jquery

My js script is here :

```
<script src="js/jquery-last.js"></script>
<script>
     function ajax(id,type)
     {
         var param = 'read=' + id + ',type=' + type;
         $("#ajax").load("themes/2/ajax_v2.php",param);
         alert(param);
     }
 </script>
```

This script is at the end of the first php file.

When I execute this code on FTP session, I am working for a website, the answer is :

> GET 
>   XHR 
>   http://www.next-war.com/2-test/themes/2/ajax_v2.php [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 97ms]

Please help me to resolve this problem.

I am sorry for my bad english. And i am a beginner in web programation.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Make sure your PHP file has no syntax error and raises no exceptions. Those are usually the causes of internal server errors on Ajax calls.

Comment: Then it was clear that your file `ajax_v2.php` has some errors inside it. You shall fix that first

Comment: Thanks I will study this, I didn't know that syntax errors were the cause of this problem. I will study this and i will tell you :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the vars on the url with GET (not recommended) you have to concatenate in this way

```
 read=1&type=2
```

but if prefers hide the vars, use the POST method

```
  $.post( "ajax_v2.php", { read: "1", type: "2" })
     .done(function( data ) {
           alert( "response: " + data );
     });
```

Comment: now the error is :

POST 
XHR 
http://www.next-war.com/2-test/ajax_v2.php [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 54ms]

Comment: a 404 error occurs when the file that you are calling not exist

Comment: and if I replace "ajax_v2.php" by "themes/2/ajax_v2.php" the complete path the servor return the same error as before (500)

Comment: the probleme is with this I can't choose what i want to replace whereas with load method i can specify an id, it was "ajax"

Comment: maybe with the ajax_v2.php code we could find the problem